# in ggplot2, how to adjust legend sequence as the bar sequence

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

in ggplot2, how to adjust legend sequence as the bar sequence ?  (top to bottom ,want to ajust legend sequence from 'abcd' to 'dcba')

```
plot_data <- data.frame(cat=c('a','b','c','d'),value=c(1:4))
plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x='1',y=value,fill=cat))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = position_stack(reverse=TRUE))+
  geom_text(aes(label=value),position = position_stack(reverse=TRUE,vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to `position_stack` you could reverse the order in the legend via the `reverse` argument of `guide_legend`, i.e. do `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- data.frame(cat = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), value = c(1:4))
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = "1", y = value, fill = cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]